# Replace the URLs entered in a textarea with "url_removed"

Tags: webforms

I am using Drupal 8.9.1 and Webform module 8.5.16. I looking for the best way to either replace all URLs that a user might enter in a text area with "url_removed" or not allow the user to enter a functioning URL.

The goal is to prevent webform submission emails from having potentially malicious links within them the body of a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding your text area to the webform you can set form validation and use a regex that makes sure the text is free of urls.  Something like:

/^(?!.*(http|www|ftp|file|data|irc)).*$/gmi

You definitely want to revise the actual regex as Im sure this one is not all inclusive.  I'm far from a regex expert.

Comment: Built upon this concept but used it in a webform submission handler.